# Docker Desktop not starting up in windows 10 with WSL2 enabled

Tags: windows, docker

Docker Desktop is not starting up with WSL2 Enabled and below is the stack trace? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
System.TimeoutException:
Timed out waiting for the lifecycle-server to start.
This may be the result of a slow environment or there may be a real problem.
This timeout can be increased by editing settings.json, value 'lifecycleTimeoutSeconds'.
This file is usually in C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Roaming\Docker
   at Docker.ApiServices.LifecycleClient.<WaitForServerUpAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\LifecycleClient.cs:line 84
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 148
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

Comment: let me know if this fix the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026771/my-docker-is-failing-to-launch-on-my-windows-10-pro/66036200#66036200

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I resolved it following the instructions in the error. Have you tried that?

Long story short, change the `lifecycleTimeoutSeconds` setting in `C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json` from `600` to `3600`, and restart Docker Desktop.

Researching a bit the problem and what would be a proper value to set, this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4393) and this [comment](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4393#issuecomment-523815619) in particular helped. But in essence, the conclusion is the error message has it all, except the actual value (`3600`) to put and precise file (`setttings.json`) that owns it.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped total disabling of Exploit Protection in Windows 10 Pro

1. Windows Security
2. App & browser control
3. Exploit protection

If you are going to try please also check overriding of default settings on `Program Settings` tab for `c:\Windows\System32\vmcompute.exe` process.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a very trivial problem:

docker uses my only wsl2 distro (ubuntu), which i also use ocassionally in the terminal, so i installed oh-my-zsh for convenience. a simple, unanswered "wanna update oh-my-zsh?" prompt was blocking the terminal, not only for me but for docker as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. This also happened with WSL2 disabled.
The setting `lifecycleTimeoutSeconds` has to be present, as mentioned earlier.
Setting it to `3600` means a timeout of 1 hour.
It seems the Docker Desktop backend process tries to access some external location but does not succeed and tries until the timeout occurs. Waiting an hour for that seems a long time. A value of `600` seems to work too but I still need to wait for 10 minutes.

I expect the access problem is caused by the Company firewall. I did not find a way to fix this yet.

As a workaround, however, I did the following:

- set `lifecycleTimeoutSeconds` to 10
- start docker desktop (unfortunately it does NOT start within 10 seconds)
- in the Windows task manager: kill process 'Docker Desktop Backend'
- close the Docker Desktop window
- start Docker Desktop again: now it starts within a few seconds

This workaround has worked consistently for a week now.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one has the same problem. I had disabled automatic updates.

- First close docker using the task manager and run`wsl --shutdown` on powershell.
- Then change `lifecycleTimeoutSeconds` to 5 seconds in order to be able to enter the interface.
- Re-enter docker, update it and restart it.
- Lastly, set `autoDownloadUpdates` to `true` to ensure that is always updated.

So far it's working for me.